# how to compare data from Firebase database with data entered from Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a system that uses numbers with an ID and password. I want to contrast whether the data entered in the edittext matches the data stored in the firebase realtime database.

firebase structure:

```
"password" : {
   12345 : 1111,
   54321 : 2222
}
```

12345 and 54321 are IDs and 1111 and 2222 are passwords.

java code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
             String server_data_User = dataSnapshot.child("password").getKey();
             Log.d("PWActivity", "ValueEventListener : " + server_data_User);

             String server_data_PW = dataSnapshot.child("password").getValue(String.class);
             Log.d("PWActivity", "ValueEventListener : " + server_data_PW);

             String EditText_user = editText.getText().toString();
             String server_user = server_data_User;

             String EditText_pw = editText.getText().toString();
             String server_pw = server_data_PW;

             if (EditText_user.equals(server_user) && EditText_pw.equals(server_pw))
                 {
                     Intent intent = new Intent(PWActivity.this, SubActivity.class);
                     startActivity(intent);

                 } else {
                 textView.setText("incorrect");
                 editText.setText("");
                 }
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      }
   });
}
```

For example, if I put 12345 and 1111, these numbers are the same as the data in the Firebase realtime database, so it has to move on to the next screen. But even if I enter the correct data, it goes back to the first screen. I want to know how to solve this problem or how to contrast the entered data with the data in the firebase.
I tried to solve it by myself, but unfortunately I failed... I want you to help me solve this problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to load only the data that you actually need, which in this case is `/password/$user`. So your code with that would be:

```
FirebaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
FirebaseReference passwordRef = rootRef.child("password");

String EditText_user = editText.getText().toString();
String EditText_pw = editText.getText().toString();

FirebaseReference userRef = passwordRef.child(EditText_user);
userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
         String server_data_PW = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

         if (EditText_pw.equals(server_data_PW)) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(PWActivity.this, SubActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent);

         } else {
             textView.setText("incorrect");
             editText.setText("");
         }
      }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
  }
```

Comment: That code is approved unconditionally if the password exists on the server even if the ID and password do not match. Do you know how to find a node with the same name as the entered data? I tried using equalTo(), but it didn't work.

Comment: That behavior sounds unlikely. Did you already put a breakpoint on `if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {`, run in a debugger, and step through the code? Does it get there? Does the snapshot exist, even when you enter a non-existing user? Does it get to the password check in that case?

Comment: I debugged and found that 'DataSnapshot {key = EditText_pw, value = null}'...

Comment: That sounds like you have a key/property called `EditText_pw` in your database, which is not what the JSON in your question looks like. Please make sure we can see the exact data that you're using.

Comment: There was a mistake in the variable name... I fixed it, and it worked out! Thank you!